# Mocking a Socket Server in Android

Tags: android, mocking, okhttp

I'm developing an application which uses a socket serve for a multi-player game. However, the server is still under development and I need to mock a server in my code to be able to test and create a demo application. Is there any library that I can use to create an "embedded server" in my application that would respond to the requests.

I've looked at Okhttp's [Mock Web Server](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) but couldn't find a way to mock a socket server. Especially, mocking the initial delayed message that indicates the game started and them responding to different types of messages.

Comment: Did you finally find a solution? I am also looking for the same.

Comment: @Anshul I ended up using nanohttpd to create a mock server and start in in Application class, not the cleanest solution but at least it worked for my case. Here's the link for nanohttp 
https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Comment: Thanks, I will try the same.